# Seeking GIS tools for simulating landscape fragmentation?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, references, simulation, landscape

I am currently looking for any GIS packages (or add-ons) that allow the simulation of landscape fragmentation on raster data.

Maybe also other software than GIS tools?

Does anyone of you have had experience with that issue already and can suggest a good tool for that task?

Info on tutorials etc. are also welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

I would recommend either Qrule or SIMMAP. The suitability of a given model is dependent on what type of neutral landscape structure you wish to simulate (e.g., edge fractal dimension, mean patch size, juxtaposition, etc...).

Qrule:
http://www.umces.edu/al/program/gardner/qrule

SIMMAP:
http://www2.montes.upm.es/personales/saura/software.html

---

I am not sure what tools you are looking for (not sure what do you want to simulate) but there are few programs that deal with landscape indices:

Fragstats - http://www.umass.edu/landeco/research/fragstats/fragstats.html

Patch Analyst -  ArcGIS add-on (link to presentation - http://www.cnr.uidaho.edu/rsgis/docs/Fragmentaiton.pdf)

GRASS GIS have a module for this- r.le or r.li.

SAGA GIS may have some tools, depending what indices you want to calculate (http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html).

LandFrag - is something you may have a look at as well (http://placeways.com/products/landfragtool.php)

Placeways does have also software that allows for more extensive calculation, so have look at theirs site.